# Do I need to check for normality in a one-way test (in R)?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, nonparametric, normality-assumption

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r

Here it says when the `LeveneTest` has small p-value we can use the alternative one

```
$oneway.test(...,var.equal=FALSE)$
```

but it doesn't mention how to check or if I need to check for the normality of the residuals.

Follow up question, regardless of the LeveneTest result (i.e. if the `LeveneTest` big `p-value`, and I use `ANOVA` (lm function) for example), can I use the CLT to assume normality of the residuals `if n>>30`?

Comment: A quick google search says that Welch's one way ANOVA is robust to normality violation, so I'd say you'll be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)

Comment: Not necessarily definitive, but the first line in the [documentation for oneway.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/oneway.test) is "Test whether two or more samples from normal distributions have the same means."

Comment: As to your followup question, see the answer by Frank Harrell [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195452/role-of-central-limit-theorem-in-one-way-anova).

Comment: @LAP, I think with such a broad statement, you'll have to bring some quality citations.  I'm rather suspicious of the conclusion.

Comment: I admit that the sources were not really citeworthy...

Comment: @LAP,  the issue may be less about the sources per se than the overly-broad statement.  I suspect Welch's anova is somewhat robust to deviations from normality, but the question is "How much?"  Unfortunately, most sources aren't particularly helpful on this matter, especially for students and young analysts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar question [about t-test or nonparametric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/how-to-choose-between-t-test-or-non-parametric-test-e-g-wilcoxon-in-small-sampl) with very good answers, most of which can be applied to ANOVA. See also this very relevant post:  [Role of central limit theorem in ANOVA (with an answer by Frank Harrell)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195452/role-of-central-limit-theorem-in-one-way-anova).

But the practice you are alluding to, choose which test to apply after seeing the results of some preliminary test of normality, **is strongly advised against**.  If you are not reasonably sure about the normality assumption, choose some test which do not depend on it, at the outset! In `R` that could be `kruskal.test`.

That practice is called a multi-step procedure, and does not in general have the usual properties. So you cannot longer trust computed p-values are correct.  You could of course still do normality tests or qq-plots, but to learn for the future (probably you will see some similar problems in the future).

You could look at the `R` package (on CRAN) for package `WRS` which have modern nonparametric methods.  See [this expository article by Rand Wilcox: New statistical methods would let researchers deal with data in better, more robust ways](https://theconversation.com/new-statistical-methods-would-let-researchers-deal-with-data-in-better-more-robust-ways-67981).

Your **follow-up question**: If sample size is large in all the groups, then you can use the central-limit theorem to justify normal-based inference, **but not to justify normality of the residuals**. The CLT is about means, not about individual random variables.  But then analysis will be based only on large-sample approximations, which only can guarantee approximately correct significance levels. Alternative analysis could well give much more powerful tests, so if you are not (from theory/experience) reasonably sure about the normal assumption, **better to plan to use tests that do not depend on it**.