# How to construct confidence intervals for log normal using boot function in R

Tags: normal-distribution, bootstrap, lognormal-distribution

So, the sample mean for the log-normal is defined as $exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$. So, I made the boot statistic function as follows:

```
boot_mean <- function(data, ind){
 exp(base::mean(data[ind])+var(data[ind])/2)
}
```

Then the simulation function:

```
bs_sim <- function(n, bs_N, mju){
  bs <-  boot(rlnorm(n, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 0.5), statistic = boot_mean, R = bs_N)
     prod(boot.ci(bs)$perc[4:5] - mju)
}
```

Here is the function that computes the precision of bootstrap intervals:

```
prec_bs <- function(n, N, bs_N,  mju){
  rez <- replicate(N, bs_sim(n, bs_N, mju))
  length(rez[rez<0])/N
}
```

When I apply the prec_bs to data

```
prec_bs(n = 50, N = 500, bs_N = 1000, mju = 1))
```

I get value zero.
When I just apply the boot.ci(boot()) function to generated rlnorm() data, I get unreasonable confidence intervals:

```
Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( -0.38, 107.85 )   (-43.13,  83.99 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 32.05, 159.17 )   ( 34.87, 173.55 )
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It will be helpful if your code is a mwe. Eg, `mju` does not appear to be specified, nor do I see the purpose of `bs_sim`

Comment: @ChristophHanck Ok, I edited the code. I created the bs_sim function in order to compute the coverage precision of bootstrap intervals. But the main issue is the boot_mean function, because when function boot.ci(boot()) is applied to generated data, the outputted confidence intervals are completely off.

Comment: A nit: the "sample mean" is, as usual, the sum of the data divided by their count.  The formula $\exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$ is the expectation of the assumed Lognormal distribution.  It is a *parameter* having nothing to do with the sample.  This is an important distinction to know, because it makes additional--perhaps better--estimators available to you.  For instance, why not bootstrap the sample mean? One advantage is that it doesn't require the Lognormal assumption.

Comment: @whuber Frank Harrell shows [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/186957/28500) the problem with bootstrapping to get reliable CI for the mean of a highly skewed distribution like Lognormal.

Comment: @EdM Right -- I'm not commenting on that.  BTW, this problem is equivalent to bootstrapping $\mu+\sigma^2/2,$ whose difficulty is comparable to that of bootstrapping a variance.  In other words, the Lognormal assumption (when it can be justified!) helps overcome that difficulty of extreme skew.

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe simply want

`boot.ci(boot(rnorm(5000, mean = 1, sd = 0.5), statistic = boot_mean, R = 500), type = c("norm", "perc", "basic"))`

instead of

`boot.ci(boot(rlnorm(5000, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 0.5), statistic = boot_mean, R = 500), type = c("norm", "perc", "basic"))`?

You are after constructing a confidence interval of the log-normal distribution, i.e., $\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$. You construct it by producing bootstrap estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ and pass these into the function that turns the parameters into estimates of $\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$ in `boot_mean`. So, I would say, the input to `data` ought to be normal, not log-normal, for the construction to work.

I do then get reasonable CIs for a true value of `exp(1+0.5^2/2)`.

If you, instead, feed a log-normal sample into `boot_mean`, the expected value and variance, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution, will be

```
mu <- 1
sig <- 1/2
eln <- exp(mu+sig^2/2)
vln <- exp(2*mu+sig^2)*(exp(sig^2)-1)
```

so that the function value is `exp(eln+vln/2)`, which equals roughly 84, for which (for $n$ sufficiently large - note this is a rather nonlinear problem, so that even a "correct" bootstrap may not perform well in small samples), the bootstrap seems to work again.